# WSO2 CLI tools Unable to connect to host

Tags: wso2

I'm just using WSO2 micro intregrator and having issue with CLI tools, mi: Unable to connect to host
i run the WSO2 Micro Integrator on a VM using command :

```
$micro-integrator.bat -DenableManagementApi
```

and i wanna Get information about one or more Carbon Apps using :

```
$mi show carbonapp --verbose

[INFO] Executed ManagementCLI (mi) on Thu, 25 Jul 2019 14:59:47 +07

[INFO] Show Carbon app called

[INFO] URL: https://localhost:9165/management/applications

$mi: Unable to connect to host


mi init --verbose

[INFO] Executed ManagementCLI (mi) on Thu, 25 Jul 2019 15:01:52 +07
[INFO] Init called
Enter following parameters to configure the cli
Host name(default localhost): localhost
Port number(default 9164): 9165
CLI configuration is successful
```

i expect Get information about one or more Carbon Apps

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the port ManagementApi is running. By default it is 9164 since you have mentioned as 9165, is MI started with offset 11 ( default offset 10 )? Else you may find the offset in carbon.xml.

Following logs will be printed in console when MI is started with Management Api

```
[2019-07-28 21:05:05,318] [micro-integrator]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager Pass-through EI_INTERNAL_HTTPS_INBOUND_ENDPOINT Listener started on 0.0.0.0:9164
```

Here "9164" is the port of it. Please make sure that it is started and the port it is started is same as what you define in init.